# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header FFD8FFE0

Tags: java, ioexception

I'm getting an IOException in my code in the following line

```
   ObjectInputStream stream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("D:\\K.jpg"));
```

The Exception detail is:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: FFD8FFE0
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Uuh... You are trying to read a POJO from a JPEG file??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do doesn't make sense. You are reading a JPEG file into an ObjectInputStream, which is designed to parse serialized Java objects.

You'll need a dedicated class which can decode a JPEG into some Java objects, but what exactly you need depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(D:\\K.jpg"));
```